# How to create full path out of parent/child pairs

Tags: r, igraph

I have a data frame with a column which holds parent/child pairs except for the first row. It looks like this:

```
test<-c("0", "0/00", "00/000", "00/001", "001/001.01", "001.01/001.012", "001/001.0601", "001/001.089", "001/001.09", "001/001.1")
testdf <- data.frame(test)

             test
1               0
2            0/00
3          00/000
4          00/001
5      001/001.01
6  001.01/001.012
7    001/001.0601
8     001/001.089
9      001/001.09
10      001/001.1
```

The first row consists of the root "0". The desired output would look like this:

```
                       test
1                         0
2                      0/00
3                  0/00/000
4                  0/00/001
5           0/00/001/001.01
6   0/00/001/001.01/001.012
7         0/00/001/001.0601
8          0/00/001/001.089
9           0/00/001/001.09
10           0/00/001/001.1
```

I'd like to visualize this data as a tree using igraph. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically,  you have an edgelist, so you just need to massage the data into a form that can be used by `graph_from_edgelist`. That is just a little string manipulation.

```
library(igraph)
Pairs = as.character(testdf$test[grep("/", testdf$test)])
EL = matrix(unlist(strsplit(Pairs, "/")), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
G = graph_from_edgelist(EL)
LO = layout_as_tree(G, root="0")
plot(G, layout=LO)
```

[image: Tree]

To get your texty version of the paths, you can use:

```
sapply(shortest_paths(G, "0", V(G))$vpath, 
     function(x) paste(x$name, collapse="/"))
 [1] "0"                       "0/00"                   
 [3] "0/00/000"                "0/00/001"               
 [5] "0/00/001/001.01"         "0/00/001/001.01/001.012"
 [7] "0/00/001/001.0601"       "0/00/001/001.089"       
 [9] "0/00/001/001.09"         "0/00/001/001.1"
```

Comment: Thank You! I didn't thought of this column as a edgelist. Just out of curiosity (and because i'm new to R and want to learn more): how would one create the full paths i mentioned above?

Comment: Added to answer.